# Printing visual with WPF and assigning printerName

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print the page in my WPF application. I have decided to create it as a canvas, thanks to the ease of the PrintVisual() method.

The issue though is I can't set the printer name dynamically - using the Print Dialogue box is not an option either, staff must be able to click the print button and it automatically prints to their assigned printer (assigned by reading from a config file, not based upon the Windows default printer). This is possible using the print page eventhandler (part of PrintDocument, eg `pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pageLayoutForPrint)))` because I can also set the printer name (as a string), but I am trying to be lazy and take advantage of the inbuilt methods.

I'm very **new** to printing but here are my 2 questions

1. Can the printerName be set if I use the PrintVisual method?
2. If the printerName cannot be set, what is the best way to print my canvas? Is the theory of printing effectivly mapping coordinates and then passing it to the printer. EG, to print a document with just a textbox we could use the following pseudo code:

   `int left = textbox.Left;

   int top = textbox.Top;

   e.Graphics.DrawString(Textbox.Text, printFont, Brushes.Black, left, top, new StringFormat());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is embeded here

[WPF MVVM background printing databinding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192054/wpf-mvvm-background-printing-databinding-issue)

And the short answer:

1) Import System.Printing (may need to add a reference
2) This code does it (assuming there is a canvas already created)!

```
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintQueue queue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue(printerName);
        dialog.PrintQueue = queue;
        dialog.PrintVisual(canvas, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PrintDialog with PrintVisual(). You don't have to display the print dialog.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question wasn't clear. It must be to a specific printer which typically is not the clients default. EG, their windows default printer is Samsung A4 printer, but when they click print it needs to go do Toshiba Label Printer. I will update my post to make sure this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with this simple code. I regret to say that your question is duplicated.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog _PrintDialog = new PrintDialog();

    _PrintDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "Printer Name");

    _PrintDialog.PrintVisual(CanvasOrAnyVisualName, "Printing Job Name");
}
```