# DataBinding issue for first printed UserControl

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, printing

I'm trying to print Usercontrol's as pages. It works very well except for the first page

here the code for my printing:

```
    #region Print
    /// <summary>
    /// Used the XpsDocumentWriter to write a FixedDocumentSequence which contains the UIElements as single pages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xpsWriter"></param>
    /// <param name="uiElements"></param>
    private void PrintUIElements(XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter, List<UIElement> uiElements)
    {
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = new FixedDocumentSequence();

        foreach (UIElement element in uiElements)
            (fixedDocSeq as IAddChild).AddChild(toDocumentReference(element));

        // write the FixedDocumentSequence as an XPS Document
        xpsWriter.Write(fixedDocSeq);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// encapsulater for a UIElement in an DocumentReference
    /// DocumentReference(FixedDocument(PageContent(FixedPage(UIElement))))
    /// to simplify the print of multiple pages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uiElement">the UIElement which</param>
    /// <returns>creates a DocumentReference</returns>
    private DocumentReference toDocumentReference(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        if (uiElement == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("the UIElement has to be not null");

        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        DocumentReference docRef = new DocumentReference();

        #region Step1

        // add the UIElement object the FixedPage
        fixedPage.Children.Add(uiElement);

        #endregion

        #region Step2

        // add the FixedPage to the PageContent collection
        pageContent.BeginInit();
        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        pageContent.EndInit();

        #endregion

        #region Step 3

        // add the PageContent to the FixedDocument collection
        ((IAddChild)fixedDoc).AddChild(pageContent);

        #endregion

        #region Step 4


        // add the FixedDocument to the document reference collection
        docRef.BeginInit();
        docRef.SetDocument(fixedDoc);
        docRef.EndInit();

        #endregion

        return docRef;
    }
    #endregion
```

and i use it like this

```
            var pDialog = new PrintDialog();

            if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                List<UIElement> list = new List<UIElement>();

                foreach (CostumerVM item in Itemlist.Where(item => item.isChecked == true))
                {
                    var vm = new CostumerpageVM(item.VName, item.NName, item.DebNr, item.Original.Id, plan, User.Einrichtungen.refSpeiseplantypId, selectedKW.Key);
                    var window = new PageV{ DataContext = vm };
                    list.Add(window);
                }

                var xpsDocWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pDialog.PrintQueue);
                PrintUIElements(xpsDocWriter, list);
            }
```

than i created a small test version to check my print method and the result is it works fine so i thought ok maybe my LazyLoad is the problem so i created an init method

```
    // in my CostumerpageVM
    public void Init()
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (p.Name != "Item") // is part of the IDataError and it must not be called
            { var a = p.GetValue(this, null); }
        }
    }
```

but i facing still the same problem so further suggestions would be greatly appreciated

what i also allready check is

- [this solution for binding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194331/1993545) (don't know how to implement in my case)
- added a Loaded event in my PageV which **doesn't** get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fixed it by accident :) i changed my Print method after reading something more about FixedDocument and my binding no longer lost in space

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used the XpsDocumentWriter to write a FixedDocument which get created and contains the UIElements as single pages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xpsWriter">XpsDocumentWriter</param>
    /// <param name="uiElements">List of UIElement</param>
    private void PrintUIElements(XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter, List<UIElement> uiElements)
    {
        var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

        foreach (UIElement element in uiElements)
        {
            var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
            var pageContent = new PageContent();

            // add the UIElement object the FixedPage
            fixedPage.Children.Add(element);

            // add the FixedPage object the PageContent
            pageContent.Child = fixedPage;

            // add the PageContent object the FixedDocument
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
        }

        xpsWriter.Write(fixedDoc);
    }
```